# SonarQube API - How to fetch metrics for multiple projects

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

We are using SonarQube ver 5.6.6. My requirement is to fetch metrics for all the projects currently in use, through the SonarQube API. I am able to get the same, using the below API URL.

http://sqserver/api/resources?metrics=ncloc,coverage

The list returned by the API is huge. It includes all the projects created in SonarQube, from the beginning. Many of those projects are not active any more. So, I want to exclude those projects from the API response. How can I achieve this? Is there any way to specify multiple project names in the URL in the same way as we mention multiple metrics.

Comment: Version 5.8.8?! Did you mean 5.6.6?

Comment: Oops. I meant 5.6.6. You are correct.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `api/measures/component` service instead. You'll be able to specify `componentKey` to narrow the result to only the projects you want.

Comment: componentId will be deprecated in next version of SonarQube as it exposes internal structure of the platform. It's then better to already use componentKey

Comment: Thx &Julien L. Updated.

Comment: This does not allow to specify multiple project keys.